# Integrating e to higher powers

Tags: calculus, integration

Say I am to integrate $\int\!2xe^{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

What applies here? I know that when I differentiate, I take the derivative of the inside function times the derivative of the outside function, thus if I were to derive $e^{x^2}$ I would simply get $2xe^{x^2}$.

But what applies when integrating? Thanks.

Comment: That integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @Paze Regarding the current version of the question, the upvoted answer below and the comment above this one are incorrect. Did you edit the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically cannot integrate that one.  There are no elementary functions that can express that antiderivative.  You could do something like $$\int x e^{x^2}\, dx$$ via substitution rule, though.

Comment: Thank you. I added a bit to my problem which I can get a simple solution on my calculator. Could you please have a look at the new problem?

Comment: Then use substitution rule, as suggested.  Or the fundamental theorem of calculus, since you have already realized the integrand as a derivative.

Comment: I just learned about the substitution rule now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Integrals involving a product over an odd function (like $x$) by an even function (like $\exp(x^2)$) are usually approached by the substitution $t=x^2, dt=2xdx$.